# GSL Compilation Error

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, math, gcc

I already installed in Kubuntu 14.04 the latest version of GSL (1.16). I use for the installation the file INSTALL(step by step) that come with the library. I configure the eclipse-cdt evironment for use it. It work ,I think, because have a autocompletion, but when I begin to compile the program some errors appear. Please, how I can fix it?

Sorry for my bad english!!!
The file math.c have the #include

```
Building target: C
Invoking: GCC C Linker
gcc -L/usr/local/lib -o "C"  ./src/C.o   -lgsl -lgslcblas
/usr/local/lib/libgsl.a(math.o): In function `gsl_complex_polar':
/home/hacker101/Project/Libraries/gsl-1.16/complex/math.c:56: undefined reference to `sincos'
/usr/local/lib/libgsl.a(math.o): In function `gsl_complex_logabs':
/home/hacker101/Project/Libraries/gsl-1.16/complex/math.c:115: undefined reference to `log'
/home/hacker101/Project/Libraries/gsl-1.16/complex/math.c:115: undefined reference to `log1p'
/usr/local/lib/libgsl.a(math.o): In function `gsl_complex_abs':
/home/hacker101/Project/Libraries/gsl-1.16/complex/math.c:83: undefined reference to `hypot'
/home/hacker101/Project/Libraries/gsl-1.16/complex/math.c:83: undefined reference to `hypot'
/usr/local/lib/libgsl.a(math.o): In function `gsl_complex_sqrt':
/home/hacker101/Project/Libraries/gsl-1.16/complex/math.c:293: undefined reference to `sqrt'
/home/hacker101/Project/Libraries/gsl-1.16/complex/math.c:293: undefined reference to `sqrt'
/home/hacker101/Project/Libraries/gsl-1.16/complex/math.c:288: undefined reference to `sqrt'
/home/hacker101/Project/Libraries/gsl-1.16/complex/math.c:288: undefined reference to `sqrt'
/home/hacker101/Project/Libraries/gsl-1.16/complex/math.c:293: undefined reference to `sqrt'
......
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [C] Error 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely just a missing link to the math library. You might want to try adding `-lm` to your linking command, after `-lgsl -lgslcblas`.